10th Anniversary of History of Science & Mathematics SE!
In October History of Science & Mathematics SE turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Congratulations to the HSM community and moderators on this milestone.

I'm the "number 131" User, so I suppose to belong to the first wave of users of HSM and my personal recollection was of initial excitement.
But now, after 10 years, I'm sorry to say that I'm quite unsatisfied.
This site is not for "professional" historians for sure, and thus we do not expect to find here first-hand records and discoveries.
Today most of sources and quite all specialized literature can be found on the web: thus, most of questions can be answered simply by a smart web search.
This is shown by the fact that a couple of "super-users" have monopolized the site, due for sure to their expertise but also, I suppose, due to their efficient searching tools.
The result is that IMO there are too few users interacting continuously on the site and too many extemporaneous questions.
Having said that... Happy 10th birthday History of Science and Mathematics, we will wait for the 20th :-)

I am not a professional historian and my main motivation for coming to this site was to ask questions where my search skills failed. Rather to my surprise I have also answered a small number and those have been well received.
My view of the site is that it is very welcoming and has very few rep-chasers.
